# How do I get the Model instance from inside its wrapping ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, repository-pattern, observablecollection

Short version:

> If I have ViewModel, containing its Model object and exposing its properties, how do I get the model "back" after it has been edited? If the Model-inside-ViewModel is public, it violates encapsulation, and if it is private, I cannot get it (right?).

---

Longer version:

I am implementing a part of an application which displays collections of objects. Let's say the objects are of type `Gizmo`, which is declared in the Model layer, and simply holds properties and handle its own serialization/deserialization.

In the Model layer, I have a `Repository<T>` class, which I use to handle collections of `MasterGizmo` and `DetailGizmo`. One of the properties of this repository class is an `IEnumerable<T> Items { get; }` where `T` will be some of the `Gizmo` subtype.

Now since `Gizmo` doesn't implement INPC, I have created the following classes in `ViewModel` layer:

- `GizmoViewModel`, which wraps every public property of a `Gizmo` so that setting any property raises `PropertyChanged` accordingly;
- [**] `RepositoryViewModel<T>`, which has an `ObservableCollection<GizmoViewModel>` whose `CollectionChanged` is listened to by a method that handles Adds, Removes and Updates to the repository.

Notice that the Model layer has a "Repository of Models", while the ViewModel layer has a "ViewModel with an ObservableCollection of ViewModels".

The doubt is related to the [**] part above. My `RepositoryViewModel.CollectionChangedHandler` method is as follows:

```
    void CollectionChangedHandler(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                foreach (var added in e.NewItems)
                {
                    var gvm = added as GizmoViewModel;
                    if (gvm != null)
                    {
                         //// IS ANY OF THE ALTERNATIVES BELOW THE RIGHT ONE?
                         // Gizmo g = gvm.RetrieveModel();          ?? proper getter ??
                         // Gizmo g = GetModelFromViewModel(gvm);   ?? external getter ??
                         // Gizmo g = gvm.Model;                    ?? public model property ??

                        _gizmo_repository.Add(g);
                    }
                }
                break;
            ....
```

Besides that, if anyone can detect any MVVM smell here, I'll be happy to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can deal with our Models even outside the View and ViewModel layers, so leaving the model publicly accessible from ViewModel is I believe acceptable.

Let say you are creating the Models in "DataLayer" you can pass the instance of the Model to the ViewModel. To illustrate my point:

```
///Models ////////////////////////////
public interface IGizmo{}
public class Gizmo:IGizmo{}
public class SuperGizmo : IGizmo {}
public class SuperDuperGizmo : IGizmo { }
//////////////////////////////////////

public interface IGizmoViewModel<out T>
{
    T GetModel();
}

public abstract class GizmoViewModelBase : IGizmoViewModel<IGizmo>
{
    protected GizmoViewModelBase(IGizmo model)
    {
        _Model = model;
    }

    private readonly IGizmo _Model;
    public IGizmo GetModel()
    {
        return _Model;
    }
}

public class GizmoViewModel : GizmoViewModelBase
{
    public GizmoViewModel(Gizmo model)
        : base(model) { }
}

public class SuperDuperGizmoViewModel : GizmoViewModelBase
{
    public SuperDuperGizmoViewModel(SuperDuperGizmo model)
        : base(model){}
}
```

Your repository of Models will be updated on whatever updates it get from the ViewModel as long as you passed the same instance. So there is no need to have a repository of ViewModels to get the updates.

Comment: I ended up doing the same thing. The "secret" here is the `GetModel` method.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your code, I think there is something of a mixup regarding your ViewModel and Model separation.

So, as I understand it, when your ObservableCollection of GizmoViewModel's changes, you are trying to add the Gizmo instance of the new item back to your Model?

I would approach this differently. You should create your Gizmo instances inside your Model layer, and when you do this you should add it to the Repository.

Otherwise, you haven't provided enough information - or rather, you have provided too much but it is the wrong sort of information. You need to describe the situation in which you want to do this, where these GizmoViewModels are created, etc.

Comment: As I see it, in MVVM you ideally should not expose Model properties directly to the View. So, if I want to have CRUD operations on the model repository, I need to display those objects wrapped in ViewModels. So, whan I first display the items in the repository, for each little Model instance I create a ViewModel contining it.  Then, while the View is being manipulated, the Model is being updated by the ViewModel, since the View is data-bound to it. When I create a new instance of Model, I believe it doesn't matter much if it is created in ViewModel or Model, since one will soon wrap the other.

Comment: @heltonbiker - This is mostly correct, yes. However I think in your case you have a collection of Model objects, which exists in the Model, so it makes logically sense to update these Model collections inside the Model. Doing so would solve your problem because you don't need to try mirror a VM collection into the Model.

Comment: @heltonbiker, what you gain from hiding the Model from View? Apart a lot of complexity?

Comment: @E-Bat - The entire point of MVVM is to hide the model from the view. The advantages are too numerous to outline here and are already well documented elsewhere. He is talking specifically about hiding the Model object from the VM, which is different to what you are talking about. What you are suggesting is no separation between anything - just blend all your code together into a difficult to maintain mess.

Comment: @user3690202, you are missing the point for MVVM. Its only purpose is to separate application logic from UI design. Imagine wrapping every single domain object into a ViewModel, it will be a mess you will not be able to handle. Don't reinvent the wheel,  take a look a good MVVM frameworks like prism (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx) or Caliburn Micro (http://caliburnmicro.com/)

Comment: @heltonbiker, check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx

Comment: @E-Bat - I think we probably mostly agree, but are talking about slightly different things. I don't suggest you wrap every domain object. But any domain object that you require binding to should be wrapped, so that changes can invoke INotifyPropertyChanged. Yes, Prism is good and should be used, but doesn't prevent the need to have a VM. Also note that Microsoft disagree among themselves about how MVVM should work. Some say INotifyPropertyChanged should never be used in the Model, others say it should. Personally I like to keep my Model clean, so I can port it to other frameworks if I need.

Comment: @user3690202, we agree that the View should not manipulate the model directly, instead the ViewModel should expose it through a public property. Not any single domain model should be wrapped in viewmodels for the sake of encapsulation.

Comment: @user3690202 "Personally I like to keep my Model clean" yeah, that's why I'm bothering at all. I noticed my application needs some concepts for every object, like "Active" or "Folder" (for serialization). I think these don't belong to the model itself, so I can take advantage of a ViewModel wrapper to take care of these extra responsibilities without violating SRP in each model class.

Comment: @user3690202 when you say "hiding Model from ViewModel", are you talking about Model/ViewModel pairs? For example, I won't hide Gizmo inside of GizmoViewModel because they have a containment relationship. But on the other hand, RepositoryViewModel<GizmoViewModel> will only expose GizmoViewModel (because, in that sense, Gizmo is hidden inside it, hidden from _other_ ViewModels).

Comment: @E-Bat Yes, so we do agree :)

Comment: @heltonbiker You mentioned CRUD before. I like to think of it like this - if I strip off the View & ViewModel, can I still use the Model to perform the function of the system? If not, then you have functionality somewhere that should be in the Model. You should have all your CRUD functions in the Model. Your model should have ways of creating and adding Gizmo instances. You should be able to remove View & ViewModel, and slap on a console interface, or script interface, for example, with minimal work. This is how I write my systems.

Comment: @user3690202 that is a very interesting rule of thumb! By this criterion, I guess I _could_ use the repository the way you mention, and incidentally I have _chosen_ to wrap it inside a ViewModel. The VM contains an ObservableCollection whose CollectionChanged event handler contains code that deals with the repo. So in the end, the Repo in the Model layer doesn't care if it is being used by a ViewModel or by some other class. Note that objects from one layer are usually used by (maybe contained in) objects in layers above, at least this is what I have seen around, I think it is not a violation.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see here, your `GizmoViewModel` has a dependency to your `Repository<T>`, so why not pass in the repository when you create your view model?

```
public class GizmoViewModel
{
    private IRepository<Gizmo> _Repo;

    //Underlying model (Doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged)
    private Gizmo _Model;

    //Wrapping properties
    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return _Model.Property; }
        set
        {
            _Model.Property = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange();
        }
    }

    ...

    public GizmoViewModel(IRepository<Gizmo> repo)
    {
        _Repo = repo;
    }

    public void AddToRepo()
    {
        _Repo.Add(_Model);
    }

    ...
```

It would be **even better** if these methods are inside the `RepositoryViewModel` base class. You can really go crazy with inheritance here. Perhaps something like this:

```
var gvm = added as IRepositoryViewModel;

if (gvm != null)
    gvm.AddToRepo();
```

You can then simply call `AddToRepo` when you need to add the view model's underlying model to the repository.

Perhaps not the most elegant solution, however if encapsulation is what's worrying you, then you need to ensure that your dependencies are properly managed.

Comment: I'm not sure I made myself clear in the question, but actually `GizmoViewModel` has only a dependency on `Gizmo`, while `RepositoryViewModel` has a dependency (containment) on `GizmoViewmodel`. `Repository<Gizmo>` has no knowledge of the existence of any ViewModel, and both `Gizmo` and `GizmoViewModel` don't have knowledge about `Repository<Gizmo>`.

Answer (score 0):

"If the Model-inside-ViewModel is public, it violates encapsulation"

Your assertion above is completely wrong and is killing your code.
 
By setting the Model property in ViewModel as private, you are forced to repeat your self ( code smells ), as you will need to define  in your ViewModel, the same properties as you did for your Model, effectively transforming it into a Model class that mimics the Model it is supposed to expose to the View.

In MVVM the ViewModel role is to provide the View with all the presentation data and logic that it needs and for sure the Model is fundamental part of this data, by hidding it from the View you are killing MVVM.

Comment: Which is plain wrong. If you do so, you will always be forced to databind your views against your models and each change on the model requires to update your View's bindings. You haven't fully understood MVVM then. ViewModel and Model (and DTO/DAO for the case) are distinctive models and even if they match in 80% of the cases, in the remaining 20% they differ. Some of this boilerplate code can be reduced (model -> dto, model -> viewmodel) by using automappers, others can't (viewmodel -> model or model -> dao (especially in case of orm), or dto -> model).

Comment: A view model is made for a certain view, it may flat out data for easier usage, also you don't want to directly modify every change in the model as the user types in data, but only on apply button and leave it unchanged on cancel. And to bust the myth, duplicating 80% of your properties in the ViewModel is not against DRY and not a code-smell, as they are two completely distinct type of modes which belongs to different bounded contexts.

Comment: Think of DD and "BankAccount" Model in a shop and "BankAccount" model in the Accounting department of the same shop. They may share some fields like name, iban and account number but they are different models, the accounting model may need navigation properties for previous transactions, the shop don't

Comment: @Tseng, there is any gaining using DTO in MVVM, if the Model changes you will need to change something else anyway, the View, ViewModel. You cannot shield your presentation from this. Yes, some properties should be updated via business process but that is another matter. For normal properties it is Ok to bind them directly to the view, and have validation and business rules in place. If you move your Model's business rules  to View Model you will end up with an anemic domain. That said, DTO for me is only justifiable when moving data over the wire, implementing MVVM with DTO is overkilling.

Comment: Well, XAML isn't strongly typed, so if you bind model to the View, and change a property in the model, you won't get a compile error neither will the IDE refactor the names, so it's easy to miss to change the property name in a place. DTOs you also need when you cross bounded contexts (getting `BankAccount` from Shop and use it inside Accounting bounded context, since its different entities and may or may not be able to map directly) and of course for projections of queries where you only need a subset of one or more complex entity for display)

Comment: I also never proposed to move business logic to the ViewModel. Only presentation logic belongs into the ViewModel, i.e. if value in Property A changes (SelectedValue in a list or combo), load data for list B. A ViewModel is similar to a DTO, as it abstracts and encapsulate the complexity of a model, with difference that it has presentation logic and DTO just carries data and last but not least, you have the control on what you expose to the View. If you just need customer name and email, why expose the whole customer class?

Comment: Imagine you got a model that fires a domain event, when a status property changes. When you bind that to the View, it would fire up the events each time a user unchecks a box or selects an item in the view, rather than only doing it when user saves the entity. With ViewModels you can easily avoid that, each model has the corresponding properties that are set when the view is displayed, and each change of values in the UI remains only within ViewModel... model isn't changed as user interacts with the UI. Once he click save, you take over the values into the model